# Load NFT instead of LazyNFT (Metaplex SDK)

Tags: solana-program, metaplex, metaplex-js

I am struggling with the `metaplex.nfts().loadNft()`:

https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js#loadnft

I am getting a list of NFT from a wallet using `findAllByOwner()`. But, it says `lazy = true`.

So, I am trying to load the NFT and not the LazyNFT:

```
// Get list of NFTs
const holdingNFTs = await metaplex.nfts().findAllByOwner(wallet).run();

const lazyNft = holdingNFTs[0];
const nft = await metaplex.nfts().loadNft(lazyNft, { commitment: 'confirmed' } ).run();
```

And I am getting this error:

> Argument of type 'Nft | LazyNft' is not assignable to parameter of type 'LazyNft'.
> Type 'Nft' is not assignable to type 'LazyNft'.
> Type 'Nft' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<{ lazy: true; }>'.
> Types of property 'lazy' are incompatible.
> Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'true'.

Any ideas? What am I doing wrong? I couldn't find any code examples.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was use TypeScript instead of Javascript.

Here is the complete code working to fetch the NFTs from a wallet as LazyNFT and then load them to NFT type.

```
import { Metaplex, guestIdentity } from "@metaplex-foundation/js";
import { Connection, clusterApiUrl, PublicKey } from "@solana/web3.js";

const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("mainnet-beta"));
const metaplex = new Metaplex(connection).use(guestIdentity());

const wallet = new PublicKey("WALLET");

const lazyNfts = await metaplex.nfts().findAllByOwner(wallet).run();
const lazy = lazyNfts[0];
console.log(lazy.lazy);

const nft = await metaplex.nfts().loadNft(lazy, {commitment: 'confirmed'}).run();
console.log(nft.json.image);
```

Comment: You should be able to use typescript? The JS SDK was written in TypeScript and as a result is of course fully typed.

Comment: please annotated the code to point out the differences and why they make it work vs what you tried before

Comment: The code is the same, my mistake was using TypeScript instead Javascript. Just changed to Javascript and works fine.

Comment: This is a workaround (as is the other suggested answer using type coersion) rather than an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is also an answer I just crafted today. Not the most optimal one but one that includes type

```
const mx = Metaplex.make(connection);
    if (!data) {
                // find All nfts owned by an address
                const userNfts: (Nft | LazyNft)[] = await mx
                  .nfts()
                  .findAllByOwner(userPublicKey)
                  .run();
                if (userNfts) {
                  // we might get nfts without metadata (LazyNfts). We have to then query for
                  // metadata extra
                    const loadedLazyNfts = Promise.all(userNfts.map((async (eachLazyNft: Nft | LazyNft) => {
                      if (eachLazyNft.lazy) {
                        return mx.nfts().loadNft(eachLazyNft).run();
                      }
                      return eachLazyNft
                    }) ));
                    loadedLazyNfts
                      .then((allLoadedNfts) => {
                        setData(allLoadedNfts);
                        setFetchError(false)
                        setIsLoading(false)
    
                        console.log(allLoadedNfts, 'allLoadedNfts')
                      } )
```

Comment: You don't need to use `.then()` since you have async/await (and you're using that elsewhere). Just do `const loadedLazyNfts = await Promise.all(...); setData(loadedLazyNfts);`

Answer (score 0):

Typescript error says that you use the type that is either LazyNFT or NFT for a method that takes only LazyNFT. It prevents you from passing NFT type to this method. You can avoid this type of error if you use `as LazyNFT` for a value.

Answer (score 0):

@andres, your solution doesn't work, no matter which wallet you provide, it will return the same set of NFTs of the same random address. (tbh i have no idea how it is chosen in the first place)

lazy.lazy is undefined, and the last call error come back as not a function